# Script de instalação automática sem interação do usuário

Tags: cmd, batch, powershell, vbs, vbscript

Estou precisando executar a instalação do agente do ocsinventory automaticamente instalador via script, que será startado pelo GPO do domínio, podendo ser em .bat, .vbs ou powershell, e não pode haver interação com o usuário.
Já li e testei toda literatura da documentação do OCS, mas sem sucesso, pois *parece estar desatualizada. Já utilizei os métodos *psexec.exe* e o msiexec.exe*, mas a janela de instalação insiste em aparecer para o usuário.

Segue meu código usado:

```
ECHO OFF
title *** INSTALACAO ***

START \\server\compartilhamento\ocsinventoryagent.exe /server=https://162.0.0.1/ocsinventory /NOW /NOLICPROMPT /TIMER:0

EXIT
```

Mesmo com usando o argumento/parametro **`/NOLICPROMPT`**, a janela do sistema abre e pergunta se é para executar e pede permissão do UAC.

Preciso fazer a instalação sem a necessidade de se pressionar os botões **<kbd>`NEXT`</kbd>** ou **<kbd>`SIM`</kbd>** e com direitos de administrador. Já tentei fazer com o método:

```
psexec \\* -s -u Domain\Administrator -p Password \\Server\NetLogon\OCS-NG-Windows-Agent-Setup.exe /S /NOSPLASH /SERVER=http://my_ocs_server/ocsinventory
```

Sem sucesso também!

Comment: Consegui com o seguinte script vbs: `On error resume next 
 
Dim WshShell, fso 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

WshShell.Run "runas /user:DOMÍNIO\Administrator ""\\162.0.0.1\publico\agenteocs.exe /QUIET /S /NOW  """

WScript.Sleep 1500

WshShell.Sendkeys "password~"
 
'Envia senha para o usuário adminstrator'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui usando esse script em **[vbs](/questions/tagged/vbs):**

---

```vbs
On error resume next 

Dim WshShell, fso 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

WshShell.Run "runas /user:DOMÍNIO\Administrator ""\\162.0.0.1\publico\ocsagente.exe /QUIET /S /NOW  """

WScript.Sleep 1500
WshShell.Sendkeys "password~"

'Envia senha para o usuário adminstrator'
```

A instalação ocorre silenciosamente, inclusive em estações sem privilégios de administrador.

Answer (score 3):

Tente instalar com os complementos de comando presentes na resposta, porém, usando o instalador **`.exe`** , já que tens disponível na versão do instalador **`.msi`**, e também o instalador **`.exe`** para download no www.[ocsinventory-ng.org](http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org):

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**::Update baseado nos últimos comentários::**

acredito que possa resolver usando as informações complementares via comando, onde vais executar o instalador no server e informando (all.txt) as estações alvo da instalação cliente:

```
rem :: informando todos as estacoes == "\\*"
psexec \\* -s -u Domain\Administrator -p Password \\Server\NetLogon\OCS-NG-Windows-Agent-Setup.exe /S /NOSPLASH /SERVER=http://my_ocs_server/ocsinventory

rem :: informando especificas estacoes == "\\@ALL.TXT*" uma por linha!!
psexec @ALL.TXT -s -u Domain\Administrator -p Password \\Server\NetLogon\OCS-NG-Windows-Agent-Setup.exe /S /NOSPLASH /SERVER=http://my_ocs_server/ocsinventory
```

Poderia usar a ferramenta de instalação **[`msiexec.exe`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cbcffae5-9c23-4b9f-9c0e-3965509612a0/run-and-accept-licence-agreement-automatically?forum=win10itprogeneral)**

```
@echo off & title *** INSTALACAO ***

%windir%\system32\msiexec.exe /i \\server\compartilhamento\pacote.msi /qn 

exit
```

**Considere informar o nome do programa** que estas instalando, visto que  seria possível fazer alguns testes para obter informações que resultam uma possível solução.

---

Por exemplo, o programa **`Bginfo.exe`** (como outros programas do SysInternals), aceitam o argumento **`/nocliprompt`** e **`/accepteula /i`**, isso para evitar abrir janela para aceitção dos termos/licença, mas, quando não é passado nos argumentos alguma dessas opções, ele vai ler no registro uma chave/valor, se ele encontra essa chave/valor, nenhuma janela propondo aceitação de licença é exibida:

---

chave com valor de aceitação de licença já efetuada:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sysinternals\BGInfo] 
"EulaAccepted"=dword:00000001
```

---

> Ou via linha de comando/bat :

---

```
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Bginfo.exe /v EulaAccepted /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

---

Se for o caso, pode adicionar a entrada no registro ao seu bat:

```
@echo off & title *** INSTALACAO ***

REG ADD HKCU\Software\Sysinternals\Bginfo.exe /v EulaAccepted /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

%windir%\system32\msiexec.exe /i \\server\compartilhamento\pacote.msi /qn 

exit
```

Comment: Obrigado @It Wasn't Me, no meu caso o instalador é o OCSinventory agent, ele não pede aceite de licença, mas pede para que se insira as configurações, o que eu resolvi comentando /NOW /SERVER=https://162.0.0.1/ocsinventory. O problema é "splashar" na tela do usuário e efetivamente instalar na máquina cliente.

Comment: a documentação do OcsInventory está desatualizada :/. Este método com psExec foi minha primeira tentativa!!!

Comment: Bom, até o momento, somente a instalação assistida, ou seja, aquela que exige clicar em botões NEXT ou SIM tem surtido efeito

Answer (score -3):

Funcionou pra mim esse script abaixo, acho que pode te ajudar. Mude as informações. Eu apliquei utilizando GPO.

```
@echo off
IF %Processor_Architecture% == x86 goto x86
goto x64
:x86
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\CAMINHO_DO_PROGRAMA_PARA_VERIFICAR_SE_JÁ_TEM_UMA_INSTALAÇÃO_NA_MAQUINA_PARA_NÃO_FICAR_TENTANDO_INSTALAR_TODA_HORA" goto done
XCOPY "CAMINHO_DO_PROGRAMA_PARA_PUXARA_A_INSTALAÇÃO" "C:\temp\" /s /y
start C:\temp\NOME_DO_PROGRAMA_QUE_SERÁ_COPIADO -t "CHAVE_TOKEN_CASO_PRECISE_DE_ATIVAÇÃO" --qn
 
goto done
 
:x64
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\CAMINHO_DO_PROGRAMA_PARA_VERIFICAR_SE_JÁ_TEM_UMA_INSTALAÇÃO_NA_MAQUINA_PARA_NÃO_FICAR_TENTANDO_INSTALAR_TODA_HORA" goto done
XCOPY "CAMINHO_DO_PROGRAMA_PARA_PUXARA_A_INSTALAÇÃO" "C:\temp\" /s /y
start C:\temp\NOME_DO_PROGRAMA_QUE_SERÁ_COPIADO -t "CHAVE_TOKEN_CASO_PRECISE_DE_ATIVAÇÃO" --qn
 
goto done
:done
echo "script complete"
```